# Sequelize - latitude longitude in array

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I return lat and lon with a find all in sequelize, this is the code

```
 exports.findlatlon = (req, res) => {

  Prueba.findAll({
    attributes: [ 'lat', 'lon'],
     }).then(data => {
      res.send(data);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(500).send({
        message:
          err.message || "Some error occurred while retrieving."
      });
    });
};
```

and it returns a json like this

```
[{"lat": 43.355422, "lon": -0.324555}]
```

but i want to return only the values of the array with this format

```
[[43.355422, -0.324555],[43.322215, -0.343156]]
```

I tried to search many examples but there is not a solution for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to convert your json into 2D array as i have done here:

```js
var obj = [{"lat": 43.355422, "lon": -0.324555}, {"lat": 10.568456, "lon": -8.586849}];
var arr = new Array();

for(var [i, value] in obj) {
  arr[i] = new Array(obj[i].lat, obj[i].lon);
}

console.log(arr)
```

From what I can understand from your code, you should do this before *res.send*:

```
 exports.findlatlon = (req, res) => {

  Prueba.findAll({
    attributes: [ 'lat', 'lon'],
     }).then(data => {
      var arr = new Array();
      for(var [i, value] in data) {
          arr[i] = new Array(data[i].lat, data[i].lon);
      }
      res.send(arr);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(500).send({
        message:
          err.message || "Some error occurred while retrieving."
      });
    });
};
```